# How do I find cross platform compilation differences?

Tags: compiling, cross-platform

I used a template for my resume, but I'm having a problem where on windows my bullets are tabbed over whereas on linux they aren't.

I think its a problem with the packages I have on my laptops, so I looked into using \listfliles to find the difference, but I don't understand enough about latex to understand what all is going on

How do I find out what's causing the difference on windows vs linux? (I compile both with XeLaTeX)

I would post the contents of the log file, but it's 1000 lines.

EDIT: If it makes a difference, I'm using Texworks on windows and TexMaker on linux.

Also looking at the output of \listfiles I see that the first 40 lines are practically identical, but after that the packages are in different order.

Are the packages listed in the order they were imported?

EDIT 2:

The output of \listfiles on linux

```
awesome-cv.cls    2015/12/14 v1.3 Awesome Curriculum Vitae Class
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   array.sty    2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
ragged2e.sty    2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
fancyhdr.sty    2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
 xifthen.sty    2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 ifmtarg.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2a check for an empty argument
etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
fontspec.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2018/02/21 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2018/02/21 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018/02/21 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
fontspec-xetex.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
unicode-math.sty    2018/02/02 vv0.8l Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
unicode-math-xetex.sty    2018/02/02 vv0.8l Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
l3keys2e.sty    2018/02/21 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
  fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
fontawesome.sty    2015/11/04 v4.4.0 font awesome icons
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
hyperref.sty    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.11 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
se-ascii-print.def    2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
MyResume.out
MyResume.out
 ***********

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 209.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

The output of \listfiles on Windows

```
awesome-cv.cls    2015/12/14 v1.3 Awesome Curriculum Vitae Class
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   array.sty    2018/04/30 v2.4h Tabular extension package (FMi)
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
ragged2e.sty    2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
geometry.sty    2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
fancyhdr.sty    2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
 xifthen.sty    2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 ifmtarg.sty    2018/04/16 v1.2b check for an empty argument
etoolbox.sty    2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
fontspec.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2018-10-31 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018-10-31 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
fontspec-xetex.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
unicode-math.sty    2018/07/29 vv0.8m Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
unicode-math-xetex.sty    2018/07/29 vv0.8m Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
l3keys2e.sty    2018-10-17 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
  fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
fontawesome.sty    2015/11/04 v4.4.0 font awesome icons
 parskip.sty    2018-08-24 v2.0a non-zero parskip adjustments
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
hyperref.sty    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.11 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
se-ascii-print.def    2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
MyResume.out
MyResume.out
 ***********

Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 209.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `HenryBurnsResume.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )
```

Comment: it is highly unlikley to be windows/linux differences. Add `\listfiles` to your preamble then compare the list of files and versions that is printed at the end of the log. Also the banner version of LaTeX which will be something like `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2` on an up to date system, but may be a different date on your two machines.

Comment: oh for xelatex if you are using system fonts the other issue is that the system fonts on windows and linux are different so if for example you use Cambria Math on Windows, it will error on linux as the font is not available

Comment: yes the packages are listed as they are input, something rather odd if the order is different but show the lists in code blocks in your question, and someone can probably debug